# Checking and restarting threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I run several workers, at least one of them runs as a separate process, and the rest as threads.
A loop runs inside these workers (listens to the message broker and executes the instructions received in the messages).
I need to implement another worker that restarts one of the threads (or process) that takes too long to process a message, for example, longer than 10 minutes, that is, I need the thread to restart when it timeouts. And I have difficulties with this.

This is what my code looks like in a simplified form
Workers:

```py
class FirstWorker():
    FIRST_WORKER_COUNT = 0

    def start(self, time_queue: Optional[Queue] = None):
        while True:
            self.FIRST_WORKER_COUNT += 1
            time.sleep(2)
            new_class = FirstWorker()
            time_queue.put([new_class, 'test', self.FIRST_WORKER_COUNT])


class SecondWorker():
    SECOND_WORKER_COUNT = 4

    def start(self, time_queue: Optional[Queue] = None):
        while True:
            self.SECOND_WORKER_COUNT += 1
            time.sleep(2)
            new_class = SecondWorker()
            time_queue.put([new_class, 'test', self.SECOND_WORKER_COUNT])


class HealerWorker():

    def start(self, time_queue: Optional[Queue] = None):
        while True:
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 1.5))
            worker_data = time_queue.get()
            print(f'worker: {worker_data[0]}, operation: {worker_data[1]}, time: {worker_data[2]}')
            if worker_data[2] > 10:
                restart_worker(worker_data[0], time_queue)
```

run workers:

```py
time_queue = Queue(maxsize=2)

def start_worker(worker, time_queue: Union[Queue, None] = None):
    worker.start(time_queue)


first_worker = FirstWorker()
second_worker = SecondWorker()
healer_worker = HealerWorker()
parallel_tasks: List[Union[Thread, Process]] = [
    Process(target=start_worker, args=(first_worker, time_queue), daemon=True,),
    Thread(target=start_worker, args=(second_worker, time_queue), daemon=True,),
    Thread(target=start_worker, args=(healer_worker, time_queue), daemon=True,),
]


for task in parallel_tasks:
    task.start()
for task in parallel_tasks:
    task.join()
```

The main problem is how to implement the restart_worker method

I'm trying to make a timeout check using multi-processing queues so that each thread writes a message about its status and the current time to this queue, respectively, if the HealerWorker receives a message from the queue and sees that the time record has not been updated for more than a specified amount of time, then The thread or process is being restarted.
Perhaps there is some simpler mechanism for restarting threads after a timeout?

Comment: In general, there is no safe way for a process to continue running after one of its threads has been forcibly killed. If your thread cannot abandon the job on its own when the job takes too long, then your best option probably would be to perform the job in a subordinate process that _can_ be safely killed by the parent process.